# Gateway is reachable from the vm but the other machines in the network are not reachable (Destination host is not reachable)

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm pretty new in the field of virtualization. I'm using esxi to manage my virtual machines. I have 2 networks, one is the local network with the gateway `192.168.0.1` and the other is the main network of my system. I have three vms that two of them are assigned static ip addresses and they also have access to the local network.
The third vm has no static ips, but I want it to access the local network.
I have added both networks to all vms in esxi and changed the network script files as below:

vm1- File: ifcfg-ens224 :

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=ens224
DEVICE=ens224
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.0.101
PREFIX=29
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
```

Vm2: File: ifcfg-ens224 :

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=ens224
DEVICE=ens224
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.0.102
PREFIX=29
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
```

Vm3: File: ifcfg-ens224

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=ens224
DEVICE=ens224
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.0.103
PREFIX=29
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
```

I am able to ping `192.168.0.101` from **vm2** and ping `192.168.0.102` from **vm1**. But I can't ping `192.168.0.103` from them. And also I'm able to ping the gateway (`192.168.0.1`) from **vm3**, But when I try pinging others (i.e: `192.168.0.101`) it results in **Destination host unreachable** error. I will be grateful for any ideas that mention what I'm doing wrong here or what is missing.

Comment: 192.168.0.101/29 is not in the same subnet as the gateway.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hosts have IP addresses: 192.168.0.103/29, 192.168.0.102/29 and 192.168.0.101/29. This whole /29 subnet contains addresses in the range of 192.168.0.97-192.168.0.102. **The IP 192.168.0.103/29 is not a valid IP to give to a host, it is a broadcast IP.** Also, the gateway has the IP of 192.168.0.1, so the hosts in that subnet don't know about it, as it resides in a completely different subnet.

To break it down:

```
Address:   192.168.0.103         11000000.10101000.00000000.01100 111
Netmask:   255.255.255.248 = 29  11111111.11111111.11111111.11111 000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.7               00000000.00000000.00000000.00000 111
=>
Network:   192.168.0.96/29       11000000.10101000.00000000.01100 000 (Class C)
Broadcast: 192.168.0.103         11000000.10101000.00000000.01100 111
HostMin:   192.168.0.97          11000000.10101000.00000000.01100 001
HostMax:   192.168.0.102         11000000.10101000.00000000.01100 110
Hosts/Net: 6                     (Private Internet)
```

You need to redesign the network addressing so that the IP addresses are valid. You can use a subnetting calculator such as this [one](http://jodies.de/ipcalc).

**The easiest solution for you would be changing a prefix from 29 to 24, so that the range is wide and contains all of the IP addresses that you have already set for the machines and the gateway.**

Comment: Thanks! I changed the ip to `192.168.0.97` and it worked! :)